# Emit event to websocket from http request handler

Tags: node.js, websocket

Using [ws for NodeJS](https://github.com/websockets/ws).

```
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 8001 });

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('received: %s', message);
  });

  ws.send('{"message":"something"}');
});
```

Connection from the client works great.

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8001');
connection.onopen = function(){
    console.log("opened");   
    var msg = "client message";
    connection.send(msg);
}
```

This is logged as expected by the `message` handler on the NodeJS server.

I am then making a post request from another server to the endpoint `relay`, set up like this (this part of the NodeJS server running on express):

```
const app = express();
app.post('/relay', (request, response) =>{
    console.log("relay hit.");
    wss.emit('message', 'server message');
    console.log("test message sent probably");
    response.send({ result: 'OK', message: 'good hits' });
});
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(8000, () => console.log('Listening on http://localhost:8000'));
```

The calling application gets the good response.

The problem is that `wss.emit` doesn't trigger the `on('message')` callback. `wss.send` throws a "not a function" error. I'm imagining this is a scope issue, but I'm not sure, and haven't been able to figure out what scope or object I would actually need if it is.

How does one trigger an event for the WebSocket Server internally? The only place I can even find `emit` in the docs is [here](https://github.com/websockets/ws#multiple-servers-sharing-a-single-https-server) and it's not explained at all.

Comment: You will need to open a ws connection in relay endpoint, using a ws client, and after connecting you will be able to emit message which will be triggered on the server.

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru If I'm understanding you correctly, a "ws connection" being a connection from the endpoint callback to the existing listening websocket?

Comment: Exactly, but this approach is a bit odd, to be honest, something is not correct, but it depends on your implementation, maybe a simple EventEmitter will be more suited for your case ?

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru I was trying to send an message directly to the WS listener cross-server, but that question was shut down. My workaround is to send the cross-server communication in a way I know I can (get/post methods) and then have that application - the NodeJS one running both the WS and the `relay` endpoints - trigger that WS behavior internally. The idea being that my other application can use the NodeJS application to distribute WS messages to connected clients.

Comment: @AlexandruOlaru I think I see where you're going with the EventEmitter... I will have to try that